# how do i prove that the the set of irrationals cannot be a countable union of closed subsets?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the standard topology.

Let $E$ be the set of irrational numbers.

How do i prove that $E$ is not a countable union of closed subsets, **using Baire Category Theorem**?

Comment: What property does a closed subset of $E$ have, and what does Baire's theorem say about countable unions of such sets?

Comment: That isn't yet a contradiction. But a countable union of nowhere dense sets is meagre (of the first category), and the irrationals are non-meagre.

Comment: You have to use Baire? Not enough then to use a version of Cantor's diagonal proof that the members of E are not countable?

Comment: Does a countable union of closed sets have to be countable??

Comment: @TravellingSalesman All basic set theory arguments are assumed, but i don't think that is necessary to prove this exercise..